# Unity logging static methods AOP style or without interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, aop, enterprise-library

Using PostSharp I can log in AOP-style(by using attributes) static methods or methods of classes than not implements interfacese.
Can I do this with Unity - logging in AOP style without interfaces?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with Unity. Unity is a Dependency Injection container and the whole idea behind that is to conform to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) which basically means you program to an abstraction not an implementation. Programming to an abstraction means you use abstract types or interfaces and those cannot be static!

Some people see this as why DI is bad and tools like PostSharp are the holy grail in software development, but if you write your complete application using static classes you will be in much more trouble than tools such as PostSharp can solve for you. It all starts with good software design and the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) give important guidance to do that.

If you play by the rules of the SOLID principles you will automatically get instance classes that [do one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), [use Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), are [easy to extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and are hidden behind [thin interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). This leads to software that is testable, maintainable and composable. And when you have designed the system in that way, there is hardly ever a reason to revert to tools like PostSharp. It's easy to apply AOP to systems that are designed around the SOLID principles. Also take a look at these two ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590870/postsharp-alternative)) related questions.