# Log in function or function using it?

Tags: f#

Is it *best* (I'm aware of that there's no silver bullet, but there may be some advantage by using one over the other) - to log in the calling function, or the function calling it?

Examples:

**Approach 1**

---

```
module MongoDb =
   let tryGetServer connectionString =
      try
         let server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer()
         server.Ping()
         Some server
      with _ -> None
```

Usage:

```
match MongoDb.tryGetServer Config.connectionString with
| None ->
    logger.Information "Unable to connect to the database server."
    // ... code ...
| Some srv ->
    logger.Information "Successfully connected to the database server."
    // ... code ...
```

**Approach 2**

---

```
module MongoDb =
    let tryGetServer connectionString =
        try
            let server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer()
            server.Ping()
            Some server
        with _ -> None

    let tryGetServerLogable connectionString logger =
        match tryGetServer connectionString with
        | None -> 
            logger.Information "Unable to connect to the database server."
            None
        | Some srv -> 
            logger.Information "Successfully connected to the database server."
            Some srv
```

Usage:

```
match MongoDb.tryGetServerLogable Config.connectionString logger with
| None ->
    // ... code ...
| Some srv ->
    // ... code ...
```

Comment: `logger` param of `tryGetServer` is redundant in the 2nd approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach 2** is better. In general, logging is a **Cross-Cutting Concern**, so it's best decoupled from implementation details. Cross-Cutting Concerns are best addressed via Composition; in OOD, [this can be done with Decorators or Interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906547/126014). In FP, we can sometimes learn from OOD, because many of [the principles translate from objects to closures](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional).

However, instead of using *Approach 2* above verbatim, I'd rather prefer something like this:

```
module MongoDb =
    let tryGetServer connectionString =
        try
            let server = MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer()
            server.Ping()
            Some server
        with _ -> None
```

Notice that the `MongoDb` module has no knowledge of logging. This follows the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which is also valuable in Functional Programming.

The `tryGetServer` function has this signature:

```
string -> MongoServer option
```

Now you can define a logging function, totally decoupled from the `MongoDb` module:

```
module XyzLog =
    type Logger() =
        member this.Information message = ()

    let tryGetServer f (logger : Logger) connectionString  =
        match f connectionString with
        | None ->
            logger.Information "Unable to connect to the database server."
            None
        | Some srv ->
            logger.Information "Successfully connected to the database server."
            Some srv
```

Here, you can imagine that `XyzLog` is a placeholder for a particular logging module, utilising Serilog, Log4Net, NLog, your own custom logging framework, or similar...

The `f` argument is a function with the generic signature `'a -> 'b option`, of which `MongoDb.tryGetServer` is a specialization.

This means that you can now define a **partially applied function** like this:

```
let tgs = XyzLog.tryGetServer MongoDb.tryGetServer (XyzLog.Logger())
```

The function `tgs` *also* has the signature

```
string -> MongoServer option
```

So any client that depends on a function with this signature can use `MongoDb.tryGetServer` or `tgs` interchangeably, without knowing the difference.

This enables you to change you mind or refactor both `MongoDb.tryGetServer` and your logging infrastructure independently of each other.

Comment: Also see "Railway oriented programming" from FsharForFunAndProfit.com (http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) for a general implementation pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer :-) - Would the module `XyzLog` correspond to `MongoDbLog`, and then when logging functions from ex. module `Web` the logging module would be `WebLog` - or would you simply throw all functions that needs to be logged, into the same logging module?

Comment: @ebb `XyzLog` could be a logging module based on e.g. Log4Net, in which case a natural name for it would be `Log4NetLog`, etc. The point of this design is that the `MongoDb` module and `XyzLog` are completely decoupled, so there's no reason to include the name *Mongo* in the name of the logging module.

Comment: I see. Why not just wrap the logging framework into a interface, and have the logging framework take the interface as an argument? - That way you only ever need one logging module?

Comment: `let tryGetServer f (logger : ILogger) connectionString  = ...` - Note that the logger is of type `ILogger`. That would make it possible to pass in any logger that implements the `ILogger` interface. - And there would be no need for a new logging module for each logging framework?

Comment: @ebb OK, that may make sense - it depends on how complex you plan on making `ILogger`, but if you plan on making `ILogger` define several members, it may be a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

There is a more general way to implement cross-cutting concerns such as logging with a functional language. The example I have is from an async service library (think ASP.NET MVC and ActionFilters) but the same applies here as well. As stated by Mark, the function `tryGetServer` is of type `string -> MongoServer option`. Suppose we abstract it to:

`type Service<'a, 'b> = 'a -> 'b option`

Then suppose we also have a type as follows:

`type Filter<'a, 'b> = 'a -> Service<'a, 'b> -> 'b option`

A filter is a function which takes a value `'a` and a `Service<'a, 'b>` and then returns a value of the same type as the `Service<'a, 'b>` function. The simplest filter is a function which simply passes the `'a` it receives directly to the service and returns the value it gets from the service. A more interesting filter would be a function which prints a log message after receiving output from the service.

```
let loggingFilter (connStr:string) (tryGetServer:string -> MongoServer option) : Filter<string, MongoServer option> =
  let server = tryGetServer connStr 
  match tryGetServer connStr with
  | Some _ ->
    logger.Information "Successfully connected to the database server."
    server
  | None -> 
    logger.Information "Unable to connect to the database server."
    server
```

Then if you have the following defined:

```
type Continuation<'a,'r> = ('a  -> 'r) -> 'r

module Continuation =     

    let bind (m:Continuation<'a, 'r>) k c = m (fun a -> k a c)

module Filter =

    /// Composes two filters into one which calls the first one, then the second one.
    let andThen (f2:Filter<_,,_>) (f1:Filter<_,_>) : Filter<_,_> = fun input -> Continuation.bind (f1 input) f2

    /// Applies a filter to a service returning a filtered service.
    let apply (service:Service<_,_>) (filter:Filter<_,_>) : Service<_,_> = fun input -> filter input service

    /// The identity filter which passes the input directly to the service and propagates the output.
    let identity : Filter<_,_> = fun (input:'Input) (service:Service<_,_>) -> service input
```

You can apply a filter to a service and get back the original service type but which now does logging:

```
let tryGetServerLogable = Filter.apply tryGetServer loggingFilter
```

Why bother? Well, now you can compose filters together. For example you may add a filter which measures the time it takes to create a connection and you can then combine them using `Filter.andThen`. The gist I originally made is [here](https://gist.github.com/eulerfx/f43792a19e6bfc50e0ba).

Another approach to consider is the use of a [writer monad](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/a-kick-in-the-monads-writer-edition). With the writer monad, you can defer the actual printing of log messages until some well defined point, but still have similar composition characteristics.