# How to avoid multiple iterations as a pattern?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, theory

In functional languages (using F#), I am struggling to find a balance between the advantages of functional composition with single-responsibility and getting the performance of single iteration over sequences.  Any code pattern suggestions / examples for achieving both?

I don't have a solid background in computational theory and I run into this general pattern over and over: Iterating over a collection and wanting to do side-effects while iterating to avoid further iterations over the same collection or its result set.

A typical example is a "reduce" or "filter" function: There are many times while filtering that I want to take an additional step based on the filter's result, but I'd like to avoid a second enumeration of the filtered results.

Let's take input validation as a simple problem statement:

1. Named input array
2. Piped to an "isValid" function filter
3. Side-effect: Log invalid input names
4. Pipe valid inputs to further execution

## Problem Example

In F#, I might initially write:

```
inputs
// how to log invalid or other side-effects without messing up isValid??
|> Seq.filter isValid
|> execution
```

### Solution Example #1

With an in-line side-effect, I need something like:

```
inputs
|> Seq.filter (fun (name,value) -> 
    let valid = isValid (name,value)
    // side-effect
    if not valid then
        printfn "Invalid argument %s" name
    valid
|> execution
```

### Solution Example #2

I could use tuples to do a more pure separation of concerns, but requiring a second iteration:

```
let validationResults =
    inputs
    // initial iteration
    |> Seq.filter (fun (name,value) -> 
        let valid = isValid (name,value)
        (name,value,valid)
    |> execution

// one example of a 2nd iteration...
validationResults
|> Seq.filter (fun (_,_,valid) -> not valid)
|> Seq.map (fun (name,_,_) -> printfn "Invalid argument %s" name)
|> ignore

// another example of a 2nd iteration...
for validationResult in validationResults do
    if not valid then
        printfn "Invalid argument %s" name
```

## Update 2014-07-23 per Answer

I used this as the solution per the answer. The pattern was to use an aggregate function containing the conditional.  There are probably even more elegantly concise ways to express this...

```
open System

let inputs = [("name","my name");("number","123456");("invalid","")]

let isValidValue (name,value) =
    not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))

let logInvalidArg (name,value) =
    printfn "Invalid argument %s" name

let execution (name,value) =
    printfn "Valid argument %s: %s" name value

let inputPipeline input =
    match isValidValue input with
    | true -> execution input
    | false -> logInvalidArg input

inputs |> Seq.iter inputPipeline
```

Comment: This answer specifically answers about logging, but should be close enough to your question that you can extrapolate a general solution from it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24756810/126014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24756810/126014) regarding composition of logging and other side-effects in F#, in this example, you can write a higher-level function for logging, like this:

```
let log f (name, value) =
    let valid = f (name, value)
    if not valid then
        printfn "Invalid argument %s" name
    valid
```

It has this signature:

```
f:(string * 'a -> bool) -> name:string * value:'a -> bool
```

So you can now compose it with the 'real' `isValid` function like this:

```
inputs
|> Seq.filter (log isValid)
|> execution
```

Since the `isValid` function has the signature `name:'a * value:int -> bool` it fits the `f` argument for the `log` function, and you can partially apply the log function as above.

Comment: You can define it `let log f x = ...` to make it more general.

Comment: @Daniel Not if you need to follow the OP, because in the OP code, it wants to log the `name` element of the tuple, instead of the entire value.

Comment: This led me down the path.  I tried to work with the GoF "decorator" pattern traditionally applied to OOP.  I also tried to use function composition operators `>>` and pipelining operators `|>`, but the conditional prevented solving this with a simple function chain.  Ultimately, I went with a simple aggregate function. I'll update the post with my latest.  Trying to reconsider when and how design patterns change between OOP and pure functional approaches is a _fun_ journey!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't address your concern of iterating the sequence only once (which, for an array, is very cheap anyway), but is, I think, easier to read and clearer:

```
let valid, invalid = Array.partition isValid inputs
for name, _ in invalid do printfn "Invalid argument %s" name
execution valid
```

Comment: I hadn't used `Array.partition` before. This is great.  I could use this to fork execution. Will think more on the solution I updated above from Mark's answer.