# How To Completely Separate Infrastructure from .NetCore WebAPI or Should I?

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, clean-architecture

As software developers, we know "Dependency Inversion Principle" and "Separation of Concerns" is 2 main rule we should follow. Most of architectural patterns like "Clean Architecture" suggest some implementation details for us. But sample projects have some missing details. And i can not find a comprehensive solution.

My service solution has 3 project. These are:

- Service.Core
- Service.Infrastructure
- Service.Api

As I understand, I can add reference from Infrastructure to Core. And from Api project to Core. Because, Infrastructure project has some implementation details and api project does not need to know that implementation details.

According to this:

Question 1:
For database jobs, I can put an IRepository interface in Core project and I can implement this in Infrastructure project. But how can i register implementation types in Api project without adding reference to Infrastructure project?

Question 2:
Logging is a kind of IO job. In my opinion, it should be in Infrastructure project. I want to use Serilog. I can abstract ILogger in Core project but it is not enough. For example, what should i do for "UseSerilogRequestLogging" middleware ? Or what should i do to add Serilog to generic host in CreateHostBuilder?

Recommended approach:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseSerilog();
```

Comment: This attempt to avoid having references will only lead to more confusion. Just understand that the the composition root needs to be aware of all the parts in order to properly map/register abstractions with their implementations.

Comment: That said take note : "*Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that *Service.Api* is your application's entry point. That's where you put your [Composition Root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot). The entry point [references all dependencies in order to compose them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612/126014). So, yes: *Service.Api* should have a reference to *Service.Infrastructure*.

The same goes for logging implementations, but keep in mind that [logging is a cross-cutting concern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906547/126014) best address with the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). You don't need an `ILogger` interface in *Service.Core*. Adding one is a code smell, because logging isn't a Domain Model concern.

Comment: Hello @Mark,
Thank you for answer. This answer was not only what I need but it give me a good starting point. I read about some architectural patterns but it looks like I need some time and some more practice to internalize this subject. I read your blog. This [post](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same/) gave me some perspective.