# Design Pattern to make logging available without breaking abstractions

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstraction

Currently I'm working within a framework that was developed by someone else at a company I'm doing work for so I have some restrictions with regards to the architecture. I was hoping there is a design pattern or some way I can handle my logging with the way it's set up now, without breaking abstractions.

So, there is a `TestCase` class. This class is the base for all test cases I write, and any test case I develop must inherit from it. The test case has logging methods, such as `LogInfo`, `LogConfirmation` etc.

Now I have another class called `SignalGroup` which contains one or more Signals. The `SignalGroup` has a Set method which abstracts the logic behind how the one or more values are set. It does this by knowing which mode the system is in etc etc. So for instance, keeping it simple, a `SignalGroup`'s set method may just be the following in a mode that will result in setting all signals in a group to a value:

```
public void Set(int value){
   foreach (Signal signal in Signals){
    signal.Set(value)
   }
}
```

Now, in that set method, I need to log the value that each signal was set to, using the `LogInfo` method from the `TestCase` base class. My problem is, now I either need to

1. have my `Signal` or `SignalGroup` know about `TestCase` base so it can keep its abstractions around setting the value but also call the `LogInfo` method
2. Have my test case base know about the Signals within `SignalGroup` so I can implement the logging at its layer. But this means I have to make the `TestCase` include logic about the individual signals that I really would like to be abstracted away.

Is there any way I can make the logging available to the `SignalGroup` with a bit looser coupling so it doesn't need to directly know about the `TestCase` class?

Comment: What's the link between your `TestCase` class structures and the `Set` method you've shown us?  The question doesn't make this clear.  For example, why can't you just log the `int value` before it's passed into `Set`, since the value isn't modified?  Are your `TestCase`s not providing this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a cross-cutting concern, [logging should be implemented using the Decorator design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906547/126014).

Make the `Set` method virtual, preferably by defining it as an interface method, e.g.

```
public interface ISignalGroup
{
    void Set(int value);
}
```

Then implement a `LoggingSignalGroup` like this:

```
public class LoggingSignalGroup : ISignalGroup
{
    public LoggingSignalGroup(TestCase logger, ISignalGroup inner)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        Inner = inner;
    }

    public TestCase Logger { get; }
    public ISignalGroup Inner { get; }

    public void Set(int value)
    {
        Logger.LogInfo(value);
        Inner.Set(value);
    }
}
```

Use `LoggingSignalGroup` to decorate the 'real' `SignalGroup` class, e.g. `new LoggingSignalGroup(logger, new SignalGroup())`...

If you can't define an interface like `ISignalGroup`, you can instead define [Adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that work this way.