# Raised exception in the case of concurrent file access with StreamReader

Tags: c#, concurrency, streamwriter

I found a [post talking about handling concurrent file access with StreamWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882637/how-to-handle-concurrent-file-access-with-a-filestream-streamwriter).

The problem is that the answers do not manage the scenario where the file is being accessed but multiple processes.

Let's tell it shortly :

- I have multiple applications
- I need a centralised logging system in dataBase
- If database fail, I need a fallback on a file system log

There is a known concurrency scenario, where multiple applications (processes) will try to write in that file.
This can be managed by re-attempt the writing after a short delay.
But I don't want ot reattempt if it's a security error or filename syntax error.

The code is here :

```
// true if an access error occured
bool accessError = false;
// number fo writing attemps
int attempts = 0;

do
{
    try
    {
        // open the file
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
        {
            // write the line
            file.WriteLine(log);
            // success
            result = true;
        }
    }
        /////////////// access errors ///////////////
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        accessError = true;
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        accessError = true;
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException)
    {
        accessError = true;
    }
    catch (SecurityException)
    {
        accessError = true;
    }
        /////////////// concurrent writing errors ///////////////
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // WHAT EXCEPTION SHOULD I CATCH HERE ?
        // sleep before retrying
        Thread.Sleep(ConcurrentWriteDelay);
    }
    finally
    {
        attempts++;
    }
    // while the number of attemps has not been reached
} while ((attempts < ConcurrentWriteAttempts)
            // while we have no access error
            && !accessError
            // while the log is not written
            && !result);
```

My only question is **the type of exception** that will be raised in the case of concurrency writting. I already know things can be done differently. Let me add a few considerations :

- No, I don't want to use NLog in that scenario
- Yes I handle concurrency with IOC + Mutex for the in-process concurrency
- Yes I really want all log to be written in the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be an `IOException` with text:

"The process cannot access the file '{0}' because it is being used by another process."

This is a simplistic approach:

```
 static bool LogError(string filename, string log)
    {
        const int MAX_RETRY = 10;
        const int DELAY_MS = 1000; // 1 second
        bool result = false;
        int retry = 0;
        bool keepRetry = true;
        while (keepRetry && !result && retry < MAX_RETRY )
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {
                    // write the line
                    file.WriteLine(log);
                    // success
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioException)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(DELAY_MS);
                retry++; 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                keepRetry = false;
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thxs for the answer, very interested in your source !

Comment: Oh I meant the source of the information ^^  But a snippet is cool too for interested users (mine was a bit too long)